# Jenkins-Terraform can't destroy any instances

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, terraform

i have a issue with my jenkins pipeline. When i try to create infraestructure in GCP with a Jenkins-Terraform pipeline i can create VM, firewall rules, service accounts and IAM permissions without problems. But when i want to destroy the i same instances with the "terraform destroy" sentence, it seems like it don´t recognize the terraform state so after the destroy pipeline, the instances remains. Here is the declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {disableConcurrentBuilds()}
    environment {
        GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID = "jenkins-305500" 
        GOOGLE_PROJECT_NAME = "Jenkins"
        GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = credentials('jenkins-credentials')
        GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON = credentials('jenkins-credentials')
    }
    parameters { 
      choice(name: 'ENTORNOS', choices: ['dev', 'pre', 'pro'], description: 'Seleccione el entorno a utilizar')
      choice(name: 'ACCION', choices: ['', 'plan-apply', 'destroy'], description: 'Seleccione el entorno a utilizar')
    }
    stages{
        
        stage('clean workspaces -----------') { 
            steps {
              cleanWs()
              sh 'env'
            } //steps
        }  //stage

        //${params.Acción}
        stage("git clone code terraform"){
            steps {
                git credentialsId: '10879bde-beaa-4f61-8430-aec2791975ca', url: 'https://github.com/PegaChucho/Terraform-jenkins-test.git'
                sh 'pwd' 
                sh 'ls -l'
            } //steps
        }  //stage
    
        stage('Terraform init----') {
         steps {
            sh 'terraform --version'
            sh 'ls -la'
            sh 'gcloud projects list'
            sh 'terraform init -input=false'
            } //steps
        }  //stage

        stage('Terraform plan----') {
            steps {
               sh 'ls -la'
               sh 'gcloud projects list'
               sh 'terraform plan -refresh=true -lock=false'
            } //steps
        }  //stage
        
        stage('Confirmación de accion') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def userInput = input(id: 'confirm', message: params.ACCION + '?', parameters: [ [$class: 'BooleanParameterDefinition', defaultValue: false, description: 'Apply terraform', name: 'confirm'] ])
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform apply or destroy ----------------') {
            steps {
               sh 'echo "comienza"'
            script{  
                if (params.ACCION == "destroy"){
                         sh 'echo "llego" + params.ACCION'   
                         sh 'terraform destroy -auto-approve'
                } else {
                         sh ' echo  "llego" + params.ACCION'                 
                         sh 'terraform apply -refresh=true -auto-approve'  
                }  // if

            }
            } //steps
        }  //stage

   }  // stages
} //pipeline
```

Comment: Can you also provide the logs when it fails to delete the instance? Any other issue you encounter upon creation? Also, make sure `deletion_protection` is not enabled.

Comment: Hi, there is not fails, this is the problem, the pipeline runs succesfully but when i look for the logs, it shows "0 items deleted" like the destroy sentence in terraform can't recognize any instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `terraform plan -out=plan.out` to explicitly define the current state of the infrastructure, then use it with `terraform apply` or `terraform destroy`

- Apply: `terraform apply plan.out`
- Destroy `terraform destroy plan.out`

Comment: Ok, i will try it and I give you feedback later, thanks :)

Comment: It seems like i can´t destroy instances from a plan file: "Destroy can't be called with a plan file." Pd. I had to finish another project so i have just resumed this jenkins project :c

Comment: I had to comment the next stage that apparentely erase the terraform state:

                /*
                stage('clean workspaces -----------') { 
                    steps {
                      cleanWs()
                      sh 'env'
                    } //steps
                }  //stage 
                */

Then it ran succesfully.